# Does Mongodb have something like SQL "As" feature?

Tags: mongodb

For example, if I want to simplify the result set for a nested doc', get the field score.date as score_date in order to get a flat result

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible through the **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)**, in particular you would want to use the **[`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** operator. This reshapes each document in the stream, such as by adding new fields or removing existing fields. For each input document, outputs one document. Using your example, suppose your collection has documents with this schema:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("557330473a79b31f0c805db3"),
    "player": "A",
    "score": {
        "date": ISODate("2015-05-30T15:14:48.000Z"),
        "value": 2
    }
}
```

Then you would apply the $project operator in the aggregation pipeline as:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "player": 1,
            "score_date": "$score.date",
            "score_value": "$score.value"
        }
    }
]);
```

**Result**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("557330473a79b31f0c805db3"),
            "player" : "A",
            "score_date" : ISODate("2015-05-30T15:14:48.000Z"),
            "score_value" : 2
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```